# How to force Views (or whole Drupal) to lowercase page paths?

Tags: 7, views, uri

Is it possible to force Views to always lowercase URL paths? Here is a detailed example. I'm using contextual filters to filter by node field (field's name is country). Here are the node examples:

```
Node title: Madrid | country: spain
Node title: Rome | country: italy
```

Country name values are intentionally lowercased. Now I create a `country` contextual filter with this path: `results/%`. These are the results:

```
Path: results/spain
Result: Madrid

Path: results/Spain
Result: Madrid

Path: Results/Spain
Result: Madrid
```

I want the results to be available only on these paths:

```
results/spain

results/italy
```

Is there a way to force Views to convert all of the paths to lowercase letters? If it's not possible in Views, is there a way to make Drupal convert all of the URL requests to lowercase paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is untested, but I believe you can use a [`hook_url_outbound_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7) for this, since I think Views URLs still get run through [`url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7) when they get generated:

```
function MYMODULE_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  $path = drupal_strtolower($path);
}
```

*(Updates to address some comments post acceptance.)*

This should update URLs that get generated by Views, and will prevent the uppercased ones from getting out into the wild.

Drupal 7 is case-insensitive with regards to inbound URL routing.  However, I am not 100% sure this is always the case with Views arguments being pulled from the URL.  I suspect that the base part of the path w/o the argument is being matched by Drupal as case-insensitive, and the argument is matching case-insensitive because of database collation being case-insensive.

Comment: Thank you! It's not `outbound_alter`, but `inbound_alter`. Please change that, so that I can accept the answer. Are there any potential side-effects to this? All of my URLs are lowercased and I don't have any worries about that, but are there potential performance issues or strange redirects?

Comment: @take2 I will update the answer later.  This is a bit of a weird situation b/c Drupal 7 inbound URLs are case-insensitive.  I think this is a weird Views thing.

Comment: I was surprised to learn that even the default Views pages accept both versions (e. g. example.com/viewspage and example.com/ViewsPage).